# What are the Doctor's "Rules"?

Tags: doctor-who

**Rule #1**:  The Doctor lies.

What are his other rules?  Is there a definitive list anywhere?

Comment: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor's_rules

Comment: @Richard Thanks.  I was really hoping the list would have been larger than that.  I also hadn't realized how many times **Rule #1** has changed.

Comment: The Doctor has never been one for rules. Or consistency. Or having a plan. It just wouldn't be Doctor Who if there was a clear cut list from #1 to #50 that hasn't changed once since 1963.

Comment: "Good men have too many rules" - Madame Kovarian

Comment: "Good men don't need rules... Today is not the day to find out why I have so many." -- The Doctor

Comment: Given rule 1, it’s a bit hard to be sure what the others are.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Working from the link given in @Richard's comment, I've compiled the following list. Note that not all the 'rules' listed in [the Wikia page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor's_rules) actually deserve to make the cut: some of them aren't actually cited as Rules, just as "wise-sounding things the Doctor says", which could cover almost anything; some of them don't actually appear in the episodes as cited by Wikia; and I also ignored the one rule which was cited to a prose story rather than the main canon of the TV series.

### Fourth Doctor

Rule #1: **do exactly as I say.**
Rule #2: **stick close to me.**
Rule #3: **let me do all the talking.**

> DOCTOR 4: Good. Now, pay attention. I'm not anticipating any trouble, but it's as well to be prepared for these things. Ground rules. Rule one, do exactly as I say. Rule two, stick close to me, and Rule three, let me do all the talking. Is that perfectly clear?
>
> <sub>-- *The Ribos Operation* (Old Who, Season 16)</sub>

### Seventh Doctor

Rule #1: **I'm in charge.**
Rule #2: **I'm not the Professor, I'm the Doctor.**
Rule #3: *[unidentified]*

> DOCTOR 7: But there are three rules. One, I'm in charge.
>   ACE: Whatever you say, Professor.
>   DOCTOR 7: Two, I'm not the Professor, I'm the Doctor.
>   ACE: Whatever you want.
>   DOCTOR 7: And the third. Well, I'll think up the third by the time we get back to Perivale.
>
> <sub>-- *Dragonfire* (Old Who, Season 24)</sub>

### Tenth Doctor

Rule #1: **don't wander off.**

> DOCTOR 10: Rose! Mickey? Every time, every time, it's rule one, don't wander off! I tell them, I do, rule one! There could be anything on this ship!
>
> <sub>-- *The Girl in the Fireplace* (New Who, Series 2)</sub>

### Eleventh Doctor

Rule #1: **don't wander off** OR **the Doctor lies**.
Rule #7: **never run when you're scared.**
Rule #27: **never knowingly be serious.**
RUle #408: **time is not the boss of you.**

> RORY: The Doctor's always saying "don't wander off." First rule with him, actually, "don't wander off".
>
> <sub>-- *The Rebel Flesh* (New Who, Series 6)</sub>

> DOCTOR 11: Oh, you should always waste time when you don't have any. Time is not the boss of you - Rule 408.
>   [...]
>   DOCTOR 11: Never knowingly. Never knowingly be serious. Rule 27. You might want to write these down.
>   [...]
>   DOCTOR 11: Please, now we have to save your parents. Don't run. Now, I know you're scared, but never run when you're scared. Rule 7. Please.
>   [...]
>   DOCTOR 11: Rule one. The Doctor lies.
>
> <sub>-- *Let's Kill Hitler* (New Who, Series 6)</sub>

### Twelfth Doctor

Rule #1: **use your enemies' power against them.**

> CLARA: Rule number one of being the Doctor. Use your enemy's power against them.
>
> <sub>-- *Flatline* (New Who, Series 8)</sub>

### Honourable mention

... for the golden rule Moffat invented to cover ALL Doctors, which is what defines him as the Doctor across all his regenerations: **never cruel and never cowardly; never give up and never give in.**

> DOCTOR 11: Then what do I do?
>   CLARA: What you've always done. Be a Doctor. You told me the name you chose was a promise. What was the promise?
>   DOCTOR 10: Never cruel or cowardly.
>   DOCTOR 8.5: Never give up, never give in.
>
> <sub>-- *The Day of the Doctor* (New Who, 50th anniversary special)</sub>

Arguably the Doctor's final words to Clara could also be taken as a list of rules; I'll just stick that quote in here because it could count either as a list of Twelfth Doctor's Rules or simply as confirmation of the overarching rules I just mentioned.

> DOCTOR: Run like hell, because you always need to. Laugh at everything, because it's always funny.
>   CLARA: No. Stop it. You're saying goodbye. Don't say goodbye!
>   DOCTOR: Never be cruel and never be cowardly. And if you ever are, always make amends.
>   CLARA: Stop it! Stop this. Stop it!
>   DOCTOR: Never eat pears. They're too squishy and they always make your chin wet. That one's quite important. Write it down.
>   CLARA: I didn't mean to do this. I'm sorry.
>   DOCTOR: It's okay. It's okay. I went too far. I broke all my own rules. I became the Hybrid. This is right. I accept it.
>
> <sub>-- *Hell Bent* (New Who, Series 9)</sub>

Comment: +1. Never eat pears appears to be the real Rule #1

Comment: @tilley31 See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114090/pears-in-doctor-who

Comment: My point, exactly xD

Comment: The "Never Cruel, never cowardly" line appeared in the one of the Virgin New Adventures.  Can't remember which offhand, but I don't think it was originally a Moffat line - I think it was a Paul Cornell.  I'll have a look.

Comment: "Don't blink" ;)

Comment: Awarded a 'gratitude' bounty. Great answer!

Answer (score -1):

He also says 'First things first, but not necessarily in that order'. Not quite a Rule but definitely a Doctor-ism. Another one is 'Don't interfere in the affairs of other people/planets unless there are children crying'.

Comment: Can you provide sources for these "rules"? While I'm inclined to believe you, we like to see primary sources used to back up claims.

Comment: I agree they should be listed, but to back it up, I do remember both of these quotes vividly.